# Partitions Image into boxes containing object

Tags: c++, opencv

I have encountered a problem to partition binarized image with boxes/ subimage containing object (Note: the boxes can be irregular while the object is in circle of any other primitive shapes). This could be explained with images as below:

[image: binarized image with objects]

Figure 1: Image with circle as objects of interest

[image: Partitioned Image]

Figure 2: Image with boxes of arbitrary size containing objects of interest

Thus, any opinion that this can be done?

Comment: looks like a kd-tree, but won't work in general there

Comment: for some object constellations there is no solution at all!

Comment: Hi @Micka, thanks a lot for your opinion. So, it is not really feasible is it?

Comment: Any reason why a blob analysis doesn't work for you?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, well, i think it is different than what i am looking for. In this case, i am looking for subimages that is of resemblance of the whole image. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, we can definitely fit bounding boxes based on the blobs but i want something like an arbitrary sized box which contains the object that form a single subimage in which the sum of all subimages represents whole image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mentioned that:

> the boxes can be irregular

you can use the Voronoi diagram (computed by [distanceTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#distancetransform)):

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat1f dist;
    Mat1i labels;
    distanceTransform(img, dist, labels, CV_DIST_L2, 3, DIST_LABEL_CCOMP);

    // Show result

    Mat1b labels1b;
    labels.convertTo(labels1b, CV_8U);
    normalize(labels1b, labels1b, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
    Mat3b res;
    applyColorMap(labels1b, res, COLORMAP_JET);
    res.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0), ~img);

    imshow("Result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update**

If you need the boxes to be *rectangles*, you can look at recursive [XY Cut](http://www.haralick.org/conferences/71280952.pdf) algorithm. Here is a modified version of XY Cut algorithm, that makes the rectangles not touching the foreground objects, so that the sum of all rectangles covers the whole image area. Here I inverted the image since usually black is background, and white is foreground.

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<Rect> XYCut_projH(const Mat1b& src, Rect roi)
{
    Mat1b projH;
    reduce(src(roi), projH, 1, CV_REDUCE_MAX);

    vector<Rect> rects;

    bool bOut = true;
    vector<int> coords;
    coords.push_back(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < projH.rows; ++i)
    {
        if (bOut && projH(i) > 0)
        {
            coords.back() = (coords.back() + i) / 2;
            bOut = false;
        }
        else if (!bOut && projH(i) == 0)
        {
            coords.push_back(i);
            bOut = true;
        }
    }

    coords.front() = 0;
    coords.back() = projH.rows;
    if (coords.size() <= 1) return rects;

    for (int i = 0; i < coords.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        Rect r(0, coords[i], src.cols, coords[i + 1] - coords[i]);
        r = (r + roi.tl()) & roi;
        rects.push_back(r);
    }
    return rects;
}

vector<Rect> XYCut_projV(const Mat1b& src, Rect roi)
{
    Mat1b projV;
    reduce(src(roi), projV, 0, CV_REDUCE_MAX);

    vector<Rect> rects;

    bool bOut = true;
    vector<int> coords;
    coords.push_back(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < projV.cols; ++i)
    {
        if (bOut && projV(i) > 0)
        {
            coords.back() = (coords.back() + i) / 2;
            bOut = false;
        }
        else if (!bOut && projV(i) == 0)
        {
            coords.push_back(i);
            bOut = true;
        }
    }

    coords.front() = 0;
    coords.back() = projV.cols;
    if (coords.size() <= 1) return rects;

    for (int i = 0; i < coords.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        Rect r(coords[i], 0, coords[i + 1] - coords[i], src.rows);
        r = (r + roi.tl()) & roi;
        rects.push_back(r);
    }
    return rects;
}

void XYCut_step(const Mat1b& src, Rect roi, vector<Rect>& rects, bool bAlternate)
{
    vector<Rect> step;
    if (bAlternate)
    {
        step = XYCut_projH(src, roi);

        if ((step.size() == 1) && (step[0] == roi) && (XYCut_projV(src, roi).size() == 1))
        {
            rects.push_back(roi);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        step = XYCut_projV(src, roi);

        if ((step.size() == 1) && (step[0] == roi) && (XYCut_projH(src, roi).size() == 1))
        {
            rects.push_back(roi);
            return;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < step.size(); ++i)
    {
        XYCut_step(src, step[i], rects, !bAlternate);
    }
}

void XYCut(const Mat1b& src, vector<Rect>& rects)
{
    bool bAlternate = true;
    Rect roi(0, 0, src.cols, src.rows);

    XYCut_step(src, roi, rects, bAlternate);
}



int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // invert image, if needed
    img = ~img;

    // Apply (modified) XY Cut
    vector<Rect> rects;
    XYCut(img, rects);

    // Show results
    Mat3b res;
    cvtColor(img, res, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i)
    {
        rectangle(res, rects[i], Scalar(0,255,0));
    }

    imshow("Result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this algorithm works only if it's possible to make a cut along X or Y dimension, i.e. there is a horizontal or vertical line with all background pixels. This means that this won't work in a very cluttered image.

Comment: I like your style :-)

Comment: Hi @Miki, Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i need. Thanks pal.

Comment: [If `CV_DIST_L2 && need_labels`, the mask size is forced to 5×5 (`DIST_MASK_5`) and IPP-IW is not used.](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9208dcb07c015e1fda44e40bb07b43c700b4bf46/modules/imgproc/src/distransform.cpp#L745)